# Исчезает символ '\' из аргументов командной строки C#

Tags: c#

Есть следующая строка которую я должен получить из args: `-f C:\\Users\\nuser\\Desktop\\files\\`. Соответственно она именно так и задана, но есть проблема используя `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

В debug смотрю и вижу следующую картину: путь к папке изменен на `C:\\Users\nuser\\Desktop\\files\\`. Т.е получается, что у меня идет `\n`, а не `\\n` и рассценивается как escape последовательность `\n`. Почему так происходит и как это можно пофиксить?

Собственно вот, что я задал в аргументах:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот, что получаю на выходе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Один слэш куда-то исчезает.

Comment: Удвоить все слешы, строка записанная как ```"C:\\Users\\nuser\\Desktop\\files\\"``` на самом деле представляет из себя в памяти ```'C:\Users\nuser\Desktop\files\'``` т.к. первый слеш - это эскейп последовательность для второго :) т.е. ```C:\\\\Users\\\\nuser\\\\Desktop\\\\files\\\\```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков вы неправильно поняли вопрос. Сравните в моем вопросе два пути, в одном идет `\\nuser`, а во втором `\nuser`, только вот непонятно почему

Comment: Я ваш вопрос прекрасно понял, у вас теряется слеш из за того что он экранирует слэш :) и после попадания к вам у вас остается по одному символу слэша, везде где нельзя преобразовать последовательность \{буква}(\U \D \f) - вы получаете как положено \{Буква}, а в случае \n - получаете перенос строки, удвойте все слеши на входе и проверьте  :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я обновил вопрос, сравните пожалуйста *то, что написано*, с тем, *что получаю*. Один слэш попросту исчезает без причины. Если они экранируются - то почему не экраниуются все, а только один и именно там?

Comment: Вы правда считаете что первого комментария в котором написано как передать параметр мало? 
```"commandLineArgs": "-f C:\\\\Users\\\\nuser\\\\Desktop\\\\files\\\\"```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков да, этого мало, потому что даже с `\\\\nuser` все слэши **кроме одного** исчезают.

Comment: Ты считываешь как-то криво. Покажи код.

Comment: @Qwertiy использую `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, почему ты считаешь, что надо столько слешей? Они не являются символами экранирования в командной строке windows.

Comment: @Aarnihauta, а аргументы main чем не угодили?

Comment: @Qwertiy ось не указана, а в линуксах вполне и вопрос даже на работе звучал от джунов ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что у меня `IHostedService` который там где-то вызывается, но ему нужны аргументы

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, а `C:\Users\user` похоже на линукс?

Comment: @Qwertiy не исключает вызова ПО с аргументами из linux :), спорить можно бесконечно, или двойной препроцессинг(на что я и намекаю) или кривые ручки

Comment: @Aarnihauta укажите ваше окружение, поскольку на .net 5 и vs 2019 проблема не воспроизводится

Comment: @PavelMayorov VS 2022, .NET 6, Win10 домашняя

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Если предполождить, что `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` работает верно, то ты явно что-то делаешь не так, но в вопросе недостаточно кода, чтобы понять, что именно.</s>

В качестве хака предлагаю выкинуть эти обратные слеши и поставить прямые:

```
C:/Users/nuser/Desktop/files/
```

Comment: Мне `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` уже возвращает неправильную строку, думаю тут дело в самом этом методе и экранировании

Comment: ни `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`, ни `Environment.CommandLine`, не `string[] args` не работают нормально с эскейп-последовательностями, потому что стартовая строка через `dll` файл идет кор-дотнетах, даже кавычки не спасают. В общем, Майкрософтам там надо бы пофиксить свои регрессы. Я не проверял, но на феймворке 4.x скорее всего косяка нет, так как там пуск прямой через экзешник.

Comment: Прикол хотите? Запускаю с аргументами `-f C:\Users\nuser\Desktop\files\ `. Environment.CommandLine = `C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Debug\net6.0-windows\ConsoleApp1.dll -f "C:\Users
user\Desktop\files\\"`

Comment: Обратите внимание, что откуда-то взялись кавычки, и левая номральная, а правая под эскейпом. При чем если в аргументах прописать свои кавычки, то выживет только последняя.

Comment: Прикольно, но `\\n` оно воспринимает как `\<CR>` :) Надо будет зарыться в гитхаб дотнета и посмотреть, что там за костыли.